# How do I fix Parallels on OS X disabling [CTRL][ARROW KEY] combinations in a Windows VM?

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-machine, parallels

OS X has key commands set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>. Parallels can't seem to take control of these key commands when in a Windows application either in the desktop mode or in Coherence.

Without disabling these keys globally for OS X, is there a way to get them functioning how they would in Windows while in the Windows VM?

---

One solution I found is to set `send system shortcuts` to `Always`; although, this means when I <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> while in a Windows app, it'll use the Windows task switcher, not the Mac one.

The way I'm using this machine, the preferred behavior is to use the Mac commands while in Windows except for a few. It'd be great if I could have most of the commands work in Parallels except for a few such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

In OS X go to `System preferences` `Keyboard` `Shortcuts`. There go to `Mission Control` and unselect the following:

- Move left a space
- Move right a space

[image]